# Some tablets respond to pings, others don't

Tags: adb, wi-fi, linux, internet, dhcp

There are dozens of tablets on my table that are all connected to the same 5GHz Wi-Fi network. All IP addresses were given by DHCP in subnet `192.168.34.0/24`. I want to find the ip addresses of all of them so that I connect to them and use `adb` wirelessly. After unlocking all devices and making sure they had enough battery, I tried `sudo nmap -sn 192.168.34.1-254`. While it found a majority of the tablets, some were missing. Then I tried a broadcast ping with `ping 192.168.34.255 -b` but got zero responses. However I can manually pick up a tablet, go to its settings find its ip and ping it manually and they always respond. For instance `192.168.34.123` was not found by `nmap` but `ping 192.168.34.123` always works.

Why do some tablets not respond to nmap pings but do respond to manual pings? How can I ensure that all tablets are reachable by `nmap`? Are there other commands or tools that are more suitable for the job?

Comment: Similar question on Unix.SE: [nmap is unable to find all android tablets connected to network](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/731440/90391)

Comment: Android devices can temporarily disconnect Wifi for saving power when they are in idle state and the screen is off. In such situations of course they won't respond to pings.

Comment: Is it possible that something in your network stack is restricting broadcasts?